# Finding intersection between multiple clolumns of the same table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find intersection between all the columns of **one** mysql table.
What I am trying  is :

```
select * from table where 
  col1=col2 AND col1=Col3 AND col1=Col4 AND 
  col2=Col3 AND col2=Col4 AND col3=Col4;
```

I dont think this query is working fine.
Can some one suggest an efficient way. Please note all the columns are from **same** table

Comment: This question is not 100% clear. What can be more efficient than what you already have?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to use `OR` instead of `AND`. Otherwise the `AND 
  col2=Col3 AND col2=Col4 AND col3=Col4` in your query is un-necessary.

Comment: please explain what is your required output ?

Comment: The output should be an intersection of all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join instances of your table together.

```
select distinct * from (
  select t1.col1 'intersection' from table t1, table t2
  where t1.col1=t2.col2 or t1.col1=t2.col3 or t1.col1=t2.col4
  union select t3.col2 'intersection' from table t3, table t4
  where t3.col2=t4.col3 or t3.col2=t4.col4
  union select t5.col3 'intersection' from table t5, table t6
  where t5.col3=t6.col4
)
```

[EDIT] Revised to include intersections not involving column1, and to show values rather than whole records.

Comment: I think your query is for two tables, I just have one table

Comment: In SQL, you're allowed to join multiple instances of the same table to each other.  You declare each instance to have a different effective name.  Above, `from table t1, table t2`, means use the same table (in this case named "table") as though it were two tables named `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: Just to clarify... if you had two rows to your one table, where row one contained (1,2,3,4) and row two contained (2,5,6,7), would you regard that as an "intersection between the columns" where the "2" in the column from the first row matches the "2" in the column from the second row?

Comment: Or you can say, if i had a two columns with number (1,2,3,4) and with (a,b,2,c) then the intersection of the columns is 2.

Comment: I edited to address both issues.  Listing intersection values rather than rows, and comparing columns other than column 1.